# How to use multiple html files in onsenui

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

In OnsenUI it says: "Instead of creating index.html and services.html in separate files, you can also define the page content in the same page."

I don't like to have my whole app in one html file so I tried to put each template into a separate file. This is my file structure:

www

-index.html

-services.html

-menu.html

---

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://onsen.io/OnsenUI/build/css/onsenui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://onsen.io/OnsenUI/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://onsen.io/OnsenUI/build/js/onsenui.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
     <script>
    angular.module('app', ['onsen']);
    angular.module('app')
      .controller('AppController', function($scope) {
      });
  </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="AppController">
    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator">
    <ons-button ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('services.html', { animation : 'slide' } );">Pay</ons-button>
    </ons-navigator>
  </body>
</html>
```

services.html

```
<ons-template id="services.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-list>
      <ons-list-item>Service 1</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item>Service 2</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item>Service 3</ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

script.js

```
angular.module('app', ['onsen']);

    angular.module('app')
      .controller('AppController', function($scope) {
        ons.ready(function() {
          ons.bootstrap();
        });
      });
```

If I use single html file, it seems to be a performance issue. Here, If I click the button, it won't push to the services.html page. This will work if I use ons-template in the same html file. How can I use multiple html pages here.

Here what I tried..

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/A85UfnKp8LrjoXWow2P9?p=preview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<ons-template>` is only necessary inside `index.html`, not in a separated file. Delete `<ons-template id="services.html">` and `</ons-template>` from your `services.html` and it should work. The "id" will be the name of the file.